Help in understanding this example in Kechris on the Borel heirarchy
I am trying to read Kechris's descriptive set theory (self-study only). In Chapter 22 on the Borel heirarchy, let $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ be such that $A$ and $\mathbb{Q} \setminus A$ are dense (I guess this means dense in $\mathbb{R}$...), then $A \in \mathbf{\Delta}_2^0(\mathbb{Q})$, but there is no $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbf{\Delta}_2^0(\mathbb{R})$ with $B \cap \mathbb{Q} = A$.
Can anybody help me understand why the above holds ? (i.e. how is $A$ in $\mathbf{\Delta}_2^0(\mathbb{Q})$ and why is $A$ not defined in $\mathbf{\Delta}_2^0(\mathbb{R})$ ?)

I found that what you stated as a lightface is in fact a boldface. The distinction between boldface hierarchies and lightface hierarchies is very important in descriptive set theory!

$A\in\mathbf{\Delta}^0_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is easy to see: Both $A$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus A$ are countable unions of points, so both of them are $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_2(\mathbb{Q})$. The same argument also shows $A\in\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_2(\mathbb{R})$.
However, $A$ cannot be $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_2(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e., a $G_\delta$ set), otherwise $A$ is a countable dense $G_\delta$ set, but a slight modification of the proof of the Baire category theorem says every dense $G_\delta$ set must have the cardinality the continuum.

Oops your superscript $1$s should be $0$s.

@BrianO I am late to fix it by myself...

I didn’t want to mess with it on phone. Noah got it:)
